# perl print current year in 4 digit format

Tags: perl

how do i get the current year in 4 digit this is what i have tried

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl

 @months = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
 @days = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun);
 $year = $year+1900;
 ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
 print "DBR_ $year\\$months[$mon]\\Failures_input\\Failures$mday$months[$mon].csv \n";
```

This prints `DBR_ 114\Apr\Failures_input\Failures27Apr.csv`

How do I get 2014?

I am using version `5.8.8 build 820`.

Comment: Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  This would've helped you catch your coding error.

Comment: You have a couple of good answers. But I wonder why you thought that posting here would be a faster way to get answer than just [reading the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) :-)

Comment: i did not include 'use strict and use warnings' as it will not work. $year unrecognized , $month unrecognizedet etc and version 5.8.8 does not have the module time:peice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the line:

```
$year = $year+1900;
```

To after that call to `localtime()` and to become:

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
$year = $year+1900;
```

Comment: FYI - you can just say `my $year = 1900 + (localtime)[5];`

Comment: @EricFossum Yes, that's also possible if you doesn't need other return values of `localtime`.

Answer (score 17):

```
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->new();
print $t->year;
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use the core library [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece). It overrides `localtime` so that the result in scalar context is a `Time::Piece` object, you can use the many methods that the module supplies on it. (`localtime` in list context, as you have used it in your own code, continues to provide the same nine-element list.)

The `strftime` method allows you to format a date/time as you wish.

This very brief program produces the file path that I think you want (I doubt if there should be a space after `DBR_`?) Note that there is no need to double up backslashes inside a *single-quoted* string unless it is the last character of the string.

```
use strict
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $path = localtime->strftime('DBR_%Y\%b\Failures_input\Failures%m%d.csv');

print $path;
```

**output**

```
DBR_2014\Apr\Failures_input\Failures27Apr.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

One option to get the 4 digit year:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX qw(strftime);

$year = strftime "%Y", localtime;

printf("year %02d", $year);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way, I find, to get the year is:

```
my $this_year = (localtime)[5] + 1900;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

my ($y,$m,$d) = Date::Calc::Today();

$y variable will contain **2019**
$m variable will contain **8** 
$d variable will contain **9**

at the time of writing this answer ( 9th August 2019 )